# Changing a parent theme safely

Tags: themes

Im looking to edit a parent theme, and not just the functions and style files.  I find that child themes don’t have the flexibility i want.  How can i edit the parent theme without all the risk and the possibility of an update overriding all my changes?

Comment: Could you ellaborate on how child themes don't have the flexibility you want, please? In which way you find that they are lacking flexibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: Not easily.

First - just to say it: with child themes you can hook into functions, filter values, change templates or even exchange javascript files. This is usually enough.

Edit based on the comments: If the theme is coded with best practices and checks for child theme directory you may just copy the template from the parent theme to the child theme and do your changes there.

If child theme is not enough you have two possibilities:

1. Write down your changes manually or backup the files. Once you update the theme reproduce the steps.
2. Connect to your server with ssh. Install a git in the themes folder (or root if you need to). Check in your changes. Whenever you update the theme git merge the changes into the updated theme. Git is nothing for beginners. Make sure to backup your complete installation before experimenting with git.

There's no other solution imho.

Comment: So you say that a child theme may be able to do what i want.  So say I want to add a div, some CSS and JS on line 45 of my single.php (well at least the HTML and PHP).  Is this possible through the functions?  I’m not an expert and I really appreciate the help.

Comment: If you use a child theme, you can copy single.php from parent theme to you child theme folder. Then make the required changes to that copied file and the changes will be safe from parent theme updates.

Comment: Another option could be creating a custom plugin, copying single.php to it, then hooking to template filter to load the customized single.php from plugin instead of the parent theme's file. But this would probably cause unnecessary jumping through hoops.

Comment: Regarding the use of functions. It depends on where you want add that one div on the single.php template and if there are any hooks, which you can hook your custom function to, available at that particular part of the template. And you would still need some place to put your custom function - child theme functions.php or a site-specific plugin.

Comment: I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the the theme folder. This essentially makes it a new theme, so it will no longer receive updates for the original theme, but you can safely make changes to it.